# DirectX : cannot create an directx11 device even though my system says it supports it

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, directx-11

I open the dxdiag app, select the display tab to check supported feature levels here are the results

[image: Dxdiag Screen Shot]

I have low RAM today as one my chips got blown and am now operating on 2GB ram

So It looks like my device supports directx feature level 11 great

Jump to visual studio 2019 i try creating an D3D11 Device

```
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL levels[] = {                            //Supported Levels We Want 11 or above
                                D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1,
                                D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_2,
                                D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3,
                                D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
                                D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
                                D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
                                D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1                               
  };
  D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL supported = {};
 
  HRESULT deviceCreate = D3D11CreateDevice(
                                            nullptr                                                         //Use Default Adapter
                                           ,D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,0                                       //Use Hardware ,no software module provided
                                           ,D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT | D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG     //Flags for device creation
                                           ,levels,ARRAYSIZE(levels),D3D11_SDK_VERSION                       //Feature array,size of array,sdk to use
                                           ,&device,&supported,&context                                      //Created Device,supported level,context
                                          );
  if (FAILED(deviceCreate))
  {
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed To Create D3D11 Device", L"Failed DirectX", MB_OK);
    error = 1;
    return;
  }

  switch (supported)
  {
    case D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1:MessageBox(NULL, L"9_1", L"9_1", MB_OK);
    break;
    case D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_2:MessageBox(NULL, L"9_2", L"9_2", MB_OK);
    break;
    case D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3:MessageBox(NULL, L"9_3", L"9_3", MB_OK);
    break;
    case D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0:MessageBox(NULL, L"10_0", L"10_0", MB_OK);
    break;
    case D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1:MessageBox(NULL, L"10_1", L"10_1", MB_OK);
    break;
    case D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0:MessageBox(NULL, L"11_0", L"11_0", MB_OK);
    break;
    case D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1:MessageBox(NULL, L"11_1", L"11_1", MB_OK);
  }
```

Output:

[image]

I looked on my manufactures website and on windows update but both say you already have the latest drivers installed. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Go under Debug->Graphics and open the DirectX Debug Control center.
There is an option to allow Debugging with only a certain API. Maybe you have turned it on to use 9_1.

Comment: I opened the debug control center but all options in the window are grayed out. I edited the user list to include the entire debug directory and put no limit on feature level but it didn't help

Comment: what happens if you remove d3d9 from the levels? Maybe it takes the lowest supported

Comment: Yes you were right i posted the solution using your idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments removing the lowest supported feature level i.e 9_1 was the answer.

From the docs if the feature level array is null then the default array

```
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL levels[] = {                            
                                D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1,
                                D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_2,
                                D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3,
                                D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
                                D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
                                D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
                                D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1                               
  };
```

which is same as the array i passed is used and the device checks which of the feature levels are supported but **IN ORDER** and the **FIRST** supported feature level in the array is returned[Not the Best for your device]

So just reversing the array and putting Feature level 11 first in the array was the answer

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.